# Implementing slice layer in keras

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, keras

(Disclaimer: I've simplified my problem to the salient points, what I want to do is slightly more complicated but I describe the core issue here.)

I am trying to build a network using `keras` to learn properties of some 5 by 5 matrices.

The input data is in the form of a 1000 by 5 by 5 `numpy` array, where each 5 by 5 sub-array represents a single matrix.

What I want the network to do is to use the properties of each row in the matrix, so I would like to split each 5 by 5 array into individual 1 by 5 arrays and pass each of these 5 arrays on to the next part of the network.

Here is what I have so far:

```
input_mat = keras.Input(shape=(5,5), name='Input')

part_list = list()   
for i in range(5):
    part_list.append(keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[i,:])(input_mat)) 

dense_list = list()
for i in range(5):
    dense_list.append( keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='selu', 
                                          use_bias=True)(part_list[i]) )


conc = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1, name='Concatenate')(dense_list)
dense_out = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='D_out', activation='sigmoid')(conc)


model = keras.Model(inputs= input_mat, outputs=dense_out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

My problem is that this does not appear to train well, and looking at the model summary I am not sure that the network is splitting the inputs as I would like:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Input (InputLayer)              (None, 5, 5)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_5 (Lambda)               (5, 5)               0           Input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_6 (Lambda)               (5, 5)               0           Input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_7 (Lambda)               (5, 5)               0           Input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_8 (Lambda)               (5, 5)               0           Input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_9 (Lambda)               (5, 5)               0           Input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (5, 10)              60          lambda_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (5, 10)              60          lambda_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (5, 10)              60          lambda_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (5, 10)              60          lambda_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (5, 10)              60          lambda_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Concatenate (Concatenate)       (5, 50)              0           dense[0][0]                      
                                                                 dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_3[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
D_out (Dense)                   (5, 1)               51          Concatenate[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 351
Trainable params: 351
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The input and output nodes of the `Lambda` layers look wrong to me, though I'm afraid I'm still struggling to understand the concept.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321234/10375049

Answer (score 4):

Lambda are to be avoided.

Subclass layer instead:

```
class Slice(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, begin, size,**kwargs):
        super(Slice, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.begin = begin
        self.size = size
    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'begin': self.begin,
            'size': self.size,
        })
        return config
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.slice(inputs, self.begin, self.size)
```

Comment: Why avoid lambda?

Comment: how to use this slice layer?

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
part_list.append(keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[i,:])(input_mat))
```

You are basically taking the first 5 of the 1000 images, which is not what you want to do.

To achieve what you want, try tensorflow's `unstack` operation:

```
part_list = tf.unstack(input_mat, axis=1)
```

This should give you a list having 5 elements, each element having shape `[1000, 5]`

Comment: Thanks but I end up with the error `Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("D_out_2/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)` - using the lower-level `tensorflow` modules seems to be an issue

Comment: You can wrap the op in a `Lambda` layer or create a custom layer for it.