# How can I apply a keras layer on each 2d slice of a 4d tensor by using lambda and map_fn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lambda, tf.keras

Let us assume we have a tensor *x* with shape *(64,100,5,32)* which corresponds to (batchSize,Length,Height,Channels). Now I want to apply a 2D conv Layer  on each 2D matrix of size *(100,5)* for each of the 32th channels. So I need to extract 32 slices and process them with the same 2D conv layer (parameters). I dont know how to start with **lambda und map_fn** (please not use time distributed layer). Finally, I want a tensor with size *(64,100,5,32)*.

Thanks for a short code snipped how do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use a for loops with index slicing (without Lambda layer). here a dummy example:

```
n_sample = 3
H,W,C = 100,5,32
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,H,W,C))

inp = Input((H,W,C))
convs = []
conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same') # this is always the same for all the slices

for c in range(inp.shape[-1]):
    _x = tf.expand_dims(inp[:,:,:,c], -1)
    convs.append(conv(_x))
convs = Concatenate()(convs)

model = Model(inp, convs)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit(X,X, epochs=2)
```